# MySQL Entity Relationship diagram does not show the foreign key links

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a schema using an SQL script.  I have tables defined with foreign keys.  Examining the Foreign Keys window, **everything appears correct.**

I next reverse engineer an entity relationship diagram.  ***However, the links are not displayed.***

I ***can get the lines to show on the diagram*** if I edit the table, ***while in the EER diagram***, and add a new foreign key.  But the previously SQL defined foreign keys are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a MySQL Workbench bug.  I was able to get the relationship lines to show by ***reverse engineering from a script.***